# Reemplazar por un string específico por un elemento

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

No tengo un código como ejemplo, porque es una idea que se me planteó y no encuentro respuestas, sé que si quiero reemplazar un string como por ejemplo **@mention** sólo tengo que buscar dentro de la cadena de texto el **@** y el resto reemplazarlo, pero en caso de que tenga un string como este **@username#tag** y quisiera que mi output sea un enlace sólo con lo que está detras del tag como por ejemplo **@username**

```
<a href="@username#tag">@username</a>
```

Qué es lo que habría que hacer en ese caso?.
Si no me explico, no duden en corregir mi pregunta y avisarme. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

No puedo comentar porque aún no tengo la reputación necesaria pero está un poco confusa tu pregunta. ¿Lo que quieres es reemplazar el @username que se encuentra antes del #tag por una url? Podrías hacer uso de una expresión regular para ello:

```
let text = '<a href="@username#tag">@username</a>';
text.replace(/(?<=")[^\?]*(?=#tag)/, 'https://es.stackoverflow.com');
console.log(text);
// <a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com#tag">@username</a>
```

Comment: Es prácticamente lo que quiero hacer, sé que no me explico bien, pero almenos se entiende, que se supone que es un string como tinytext que en alguna parte hay una mención y la tiene que reemplazar por un <a> y de texto dentro de a, sólo estaría el @username pero con tag me refiero no a algo en específico, sino que algo que podría estar compuesto por numeros indefinidos, eso es lo que no enteindo.

Comment: Con esa expresión regular puedes reemplazar todo lo que está luego del href=" y antes del #tag.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de hacer esto. Si se trata sólo de obtener el dato que hay antes del símbolo `#` lo más sencillo es mediante el uso de **[`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/substr)**:

```js
var userData='@username#tag';
var userName= userData.substr(0, userData.indexOf('#')); 
var anchorTag='<a href="'+userData+'">'+userName+'</a>';
console.log(anchorTag);
```